# what's Chef cookbook index for?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've been trying to remove all external Chef dependencies from the supermarket and git and it's been good so far except following a line of the log from Chef client.

```
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.getchef.com...
```

Is there any way I can get the index file and fetch from the local environment? If then where is the file? It seems not to be stored in anywhere.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an output of `chef-client`.

This output originates from Berkshelf, which resolves dependencies to other cookbooks. Replace the line in the `Berksfile` pointing to the URL of the supermarket with that to your private supermarket or Chef Server (or remove it, if you don't use `berks` for cookbook dependency management).

This index contains all cookbooks and all their versions of https://supermarket.chef.io. (it actually reads the JSON file at `/universe`).